# SceneKit SCNMaterial transparency texture doesn't work properly with physicallyBased lighting model

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I have an IOS ARKit/Scenekit view, I have an SCNMaterial like this:

```
material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = UIColor(.blue)
material.transparent.contents = "art.scnassets/transTex.png"
material.roughness.contents = 0.3
material.metalness.contents = 0.3
material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
material.writesToDepthBuffer = false
material.clearCoat.intensity = 0.0
```

The transparency texture is a simple radial gradient:

[image: Transparency texture: A radial gradient]

This material is applied to a 7-sided polygon, the result of which looks like this:

[image: A blue circle with soft edges rendered into AR]

That's perfect. However, when I look at a sufficiently shallow angle, I see a reflection from *the entire polygon*:

[image: A blue circle with soft edges rendered in to AR seen from an shallow angle, but the outline of the polygon can be seen]

It looks like specular reflections are being applied to the entire polygon and are ignoring the transparency, since setting `roughness` to 1.0 *almost* entirely removes the issue. When I change `lightingModel` to `.phong` rather than `.physicallyBased`, then I also get the correct result (but possibly only because I have no lights defined? I'm not sure if it will use estimated environmental lighting in this mode):

[image: A blue circle with soft edges rendered in to AR seen from an shallow angle]

It also looks okay with .blinn shading too. However, I really want to use a physicallyBased lighting model, because the lighting estimation features are really cool looking.

Any suggestions on how to get rid of this strange artefact would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit: ** I managed to get *closer* by making `roughness` a texture that's the inverse of the transparency texture (so perfectly diffuse where things should be transparent). But it's not usable, because it results in a fringing effect where the gradients seem to not align:

[image: A blue circle seen from a shallow angle, looking a little like an eclipse due to a band of stronger colour around the rim]

Comment: What happens, if you use (for a test) the "transTex.png" as the contents of the diffuse input. And leave the transparent.contents unconfigured, as well as the writesToDepthBuffer and the clearCoat.

Comment: Thanks for responding @ZAY, I get a black version of the third image (the second blue circle photo, with the polygonal outline). This makes sense, since now the diffuse texture itself is a black circle with a transparency gradient, there's no need for a transparency mask. The artefact is still present, since it seems to come from the 'roughness' parameter.